# Sending an email automatically using c#

Tags: c#, email

This is my first experience with sending an email using c#. Everything I have so far I got from reading and watching videos. I currently have the code written to send an email. It creates it and displays the email with all of the information correct and ready to send. The email opens up and then I click send and it works. The problem is that I want the email to send on its own, without me having to click send.

This is my code:

```
static void SendEmail()
{      
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
    mailItem.Subject = "Status of Code";
    mailItem.To = "bt@outlook.com";
    mailItem.Body = "Code Ran Successfully";
    mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
    mailItem.Display(false);
}
```

I tried adding in

```
mailItem.Send;
```

but I kept getting an error. How else would I do this?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: `Send()` is a method.

Comment: mailItem.Send(); is probably what you need, but consider using the SmtpClient instad of the outlook stuff for sending email. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @StingyJack what is the benefit of using the SmtpClient instead of outlook

Comment: Its available on servers or anywhere else that outlook is not installed or supported

Answer (score 0):

Referencing Microsofts documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx), I'd recommend instead using an SMTP client (as opposed to being outlook specific).

Your code would then look something like:

```
public static void SendEmail()
{
    string to = "bt@outlook.com";
    string from = "fromAddress@outlook.com";
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
    message.Subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
    message.Body = @"Code Ran Successfully";
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    try {
      client.Send(message);
    }  
    catch (Exception ex) {
      Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in SendEmail(): {0}", 
              ex.ToString() );            
    }              
}
```